# Why python property() function is assigned to a class variable and not an instance variable?

Tags: python, class, oop, properties, python-internals

I'm learning about encapsulation and abstraction in python and i came across the property function and decorator. The common example is something like this.

```
class Celsius():
    def __init__(self, temperature = 0):
        self.set_temperature(temperature)

    def to_fahrenheit(self):
        return (self._temperature * 1.8) + 32

    def get_temperature(self):
        print("Getting value")
        return self._temperature

    def set_temperature(self, value):
        if value < -273:
            raise ValueError("Temperature below -273 is not possible")
        print("Setting value")
        self._temperature = value

    temperature = property(get_temperature,set_temperature)
```

I dont understand why the property function is assigning the descriptor to  `temperature` and not `self.temperature`. Isn't it suppouse to create a getter or setter functionality to a Instance, not to the class?

something like

```
self.temperature = property(get_temperature,set_temperature)
```

using

```
test = Celsius()
pprint(test.__dict__)
```

returns that the instance object just have the `self._temperature` attribute (Which we are trying to make private).
using `pprint(Celsius.__dict__)` returns that is actually the class that have the temperature attribute that we are accessing when using the objects, which to my understanding doesn't make sense since i am interested in creating functionality to the instance and access the instance atributes, not the class attributes.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: There's no `self` outside the method. This is defining a class attribute.

Comment: The function is defined for all instances of the class.

Comment: But why is the syntax like that. Isnt should be assigning the property to a instance variable?

Comment: It's because you're defining the template (method) at a class level. "Every instance of this class should use these methods". At runtime they'll be executed on an instance, but when you're defining the class there's no concept of instance yet, as mentioned above

Comment: Because `property` is a descriptor, and the descriptor protocol won't work if `property` were an instance variable

Comment: @DanielFlorezCortes no, it absolutely **should not** be assigning the `property` to an instance variable. *why* do you think that *should* be the case?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, sorry, i thoght that it should be in the instance namespace because i was reading about abstraction in other programming languages, and the articles were talking about only instance variables, so i thoght the same about python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There's no self outside the method. This is defining a class attribute.

@Barmar has a helpful comment above.

The commonly used class function parameters `self` and `cls` are not available outside of class functions. In this case, you are defining a static member of the class. It is implied by default that vars (like your `temperature =`) defined this way are static members of the class.

See some useful tips on static members here: [Are static class variables possible in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68645/10630957)

> But why is the syntax like that. Isnt should be assigning the property to a instance variable?

Note the below. The behavior of `class_static_var = 4` is similar to how someone may view `cls.class_static_var = 4`, however it is not similar to `self.instance_var = 4`. To define a instance var, you can use the `__init__` method

```
class DemoClass:
    def __init__(self): 
        self.instance_var = 3
    class_static_var = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't explain *why* you believe the descriptor has to be in the instance namespace, but looking [at the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#closing-thoughts):

> A descriptor is what we call any object that defines `__get__()`,
> `__set__()`, or `__delete__()`. ... Descriptors only work when used as
> class variables. When put in instances, they have no effect.

So, for `property` to work at all, it must be a member *of the class*, not the *instance*.

If you have a descriptor, `Descriptor`, and a class `Foo`:

```
class Foo:
    bar = Descriptor()

foo = Foo()
```

then the descriptor protocol will be invoked on *either*

```
Foo.bar
```

or

```
foo.bar
```

In any case, this is a *good thing*. There's no need for each instance to carry around a reference to the descriptor. Just like a method, it will belong to the *class* but instances have access to it.

Comment: It was my fault, sorry, i didnt read the documentation, i only was reading articles about abstraction and they said that all instance variables should be private, so i assumed that property should work on instance variables.

Comment: @DanielFlorezCortes that's actually *not true* for python *because* you can use descriptors to control access. Almost always, you just want regular attributes, `self.foo = value`